# Как создать Observable в одном потоке, а подписаться в другом?

Tags: android, rxjava, rxandroid, rxjava2

Использую `com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode.Barcode;`. Метод `receiveDetections` вызывается постоянно при запуске сканера. Как я понял, он выполняется не в потоке main где вызывается `setProcessor`. Я так и не смог адекватно без падений и нормальной работы настроить паузу между нахождением QRCode. В rxJava знаний мало. Если я подпишусь на поток используя debounce, я смогу реагировать на данные через определенный промежуток времени, верно?

Вопрос: как в основном потоке main подписаться на источник данных, который необходимо создать в методе `receiveDetections` который выполняется в отдельном потоке?

```
barcodeDetector.setProcessor(new Detector.Processor<Barcode>() {
        @Override
        public void receiveDetections(Detector.Detections<Barcode> detections) {
            final SparseArray<Barcode> barcodes = detections.getDetectedItems();
            if (barcodes.size() != 0) {
                Barcode barcode = barcodes.valueAt(0);
                textView.setText(barcode.rawValue);
                // Как тут создать Observable на который можно подписаться из Fragment/Activity?
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тебе нужно обернуть твой код в Observable.

Example

```
        Observable.create((ObservableOnSubscribe<Barcode>) e -> {
        barcodeDetector.setProcessor(new Detector.Processor<Barcode>() {
            @Override
            public void receiveDetections(Detector.Detections<Barcode> detections) {
                final SparseArray<Barcode> barcodes = detections.getDetectedItems();
                if (barcodes.size() != 0) {
                    Barcode barcode = barcodes.valueAt(0);
                    e.onNext(barcode);
                    e.onComplete();
                }
            }
        });
    })
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())

            .subscribe(barcode ->
                    textView.setText(barcode.rawValue);
            );
```

Comment: Как будет возможность, я попробую реализовать, спасибо!

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Работает, я задачу решил другим способом, но возникли проблемы с потоками, которые пропали с использованием RX.